# What is the word for repeating an act over and over to the point of insanity?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I don't recall that word but there is a very commonly used word for that if I recall correctly. What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't apply to insanity specifically (although it doesn't exclude it as a result), but a common phrase is [**ad nauseam**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nauseam):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : to a sickening or excessive degree
>   // a topic that has been discussed and analyzed *ad nauseam*

It can apply to both the repetition of an act as well as to the prolongation of a single act. It's an adverb that modifies something in context.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!